# Edit form and get all values (like array) from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to edit books values (quantity) on a form, and finally use Ajax to load it into db. But I don't know how to use an associative array to pass url from ajax, like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "send.php?q=" + arrayassosiative, true);
```

Form (after php load):

```
<input type="text" class="bookclass" name="bookid[1]" />
<input type="text" class="bookclass" name="bookid[2]" />
<input type="text" class="bookclass" name="bookid[3]" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var arr = new Array();
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.bookclass'); // class

for ( var i=0; i<elems.length; i++ ) {
    arr.push(elems[i].value)
}
```

But isn't associative array, so what can I do?

Comment: from javascript stringnify the array and on the server side decode the string to  get the array back

Comment: Any news about this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a form around your fileds and use form_selector.serialize()